# printing distance to label

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

Right now I'm printing the distance between two Locations inside the console, but how do I print it inside a label?

Right now I'm trying it with *self.distanceLabel.text = distance* but with this Code I get following error line: **Cannot assign value of type 'Double' to type 'String?'**

Full Code:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let lastLocation = locations.last {

        let myLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lastLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: lastLocation.coordinate.longitude)

        let myBuddysLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 59.326354, longitude: 18.072310)

        let distance = myLocation.distance(from: myBuddysLocation) / 1000
        print(String(format: "The distance to the Job is %.01fkm", distance))
        self.distanceLabel.text = distance
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the formatted string not `distance` which is of type `double`

```
self.distanceLabel.text =  String(format: "The distance to the Job is %.01fkm", distance)
```

Or like this if you don't need a decription

```
self.distanceLabel.text = "\(distance)"
```